# If $f(x)$ is a real convex function, is it true that $\forall x<y$, $f(\sqrt{xy})f(\sqrt{xy})\leq f(x)f(y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $f(x)$ is a real convex function, is it true that $\forall x<y$, $f(\sqrt{xy})f(\sqrt{xy})\leq f(x)f(y)$? $f(x)$ is **strictly increasing**.

I was writing a smoothing proof for another problem and came upon this step. Of course, it is well known that if $f(x)$ is a real convex function, then $\forall x<y, f(\frac{x+y}{2})+f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leq f(x)+f(y)$. However, what if we changed things to multiplication? This is clearly true by intuition but I want a rigorous proof.

My efforts to prove it:

Clearly, $x<\sqrt{xy}<y$. By the definitions of convexity, we have that $$f(\sqrt{xy})\leq \frac{(y-\sqrt{xy})f(x)+(\sqrt{xy}-x)f(y)}{y-x}$$

and the calculations got ugly and I got stuck.

How can we prove that $f(\sqrt{xy})f(\sqrt{xy})\leq f(x)f(y)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s false as can be seen using $f(x)=e^{-x}$. The inequality reduces to $1\leq e^{-(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2}$

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, the condition given is called [log-convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function). log-convex implies convex, but the converse is not true.

Comment: @robjohn the condition is not exactly equivalent to log-convex. May be you wanted to say that $f(e^u)$ is log convex.

Comment: @Youem: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stattement is **False** for $f$ only convex (for example $e^{-x}$). However if you want conditions such that the statement is true you function $f$ can be non-decreasing log-convex i.e. $g(u) = \ln f\left(u\right)$ is a convex.

Comment: The answer is still viable.